# Why does Joseph have a staff in nativity scenes?

Tags: art, joseph-husband-of-mary

I noticed that many nativity scenes present Joseph with a staff (in many cases a shepherd's staff). What was the original basis for this portrayal?

[This answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15240) is less concerned with the origin of the staff but suggests that it was a symbol of authority, suitable for a descendant of David, and was used in early stories as part of a miraculous sign.

Also, was the use of a shepherd's staff an original (or very early) conception, perhaps again relating to David, or a later change, perhaps a confusion with the staffs of the shepherds in nativity scenes?

Answer (score 4):

In the Luke account, Joseph and Mary had just walked about 60 miles from Nazareth to the Jerusalem suburbs (Bethlehem is about 5 miles away.)  The countryside is hilly, and there are some dangerous places too.

Personally, if I'm walking more than a mile or so, I'm going to take a stick. And, if I've got a pregnant girl I need to protect, I'm doubly sure I'm going to have a stick.  Theology aside, this would be a very practical thing to take on a long walk in a dangerous area.

As an artist, if I'm trying to remind people that Joseph was on a journey, this would b a very simple shorthand for conveying that imagery.

Comment: I cannot see how this answers the question.

Comment: He asks why Joseph had a staff. I'm giving a "It was practical" answer.

Comment: @ Yultide Geek AS I read the question it is more along the lines of why the staff is portrayed in art than, was that a reasonable depiction. Or in other words why would it be depicted in a peaceful scene.

Comment: Because the artist would be seeking to remind people Joseph was on a journey

Comment: Possibly that could be.

Comment: On a journey to protect against attack (from human and animal), I agree, one would take a stout staff. The shepherd's staff is flimsy and light and no good in a fight. Modern ones are made from 'reed' with a wire hook. So, a good question.